# Sonar way c# profile not listed on quaity profiles page

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I just installed a new sonar server (-version 3.5.1-) and added the .Net v.2.1. Plugins.

Although the sonar log provides proof the .net rules and profiles are loaded and registered, the rules_profiles table in the sonar database contains records for Sonar Way vbnet & Sonar Way cs, these profiles do not show on the profile page.

Running a sonar analysis on a .Net solution is also not possible at this time.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to resolve the current impediment?
Thanks in advance,
Maurice

Comment: I may need to add that I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Express edition in my configuration. When running Sonar with the embedded database H2 the above issue does not surface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution to the above problem was to install SonarCube v 3.6, which was released yesterday.
Thanks,
Maurice